# Connection issue with ArcGIS Server 10 map services with 931 SDE

Tags: arcgis-server

I am trying to figure out an issue with map services. I have non pooled services running on ArcGIS server 10 environment. These services connect to 931 SDE. I am observing that map services (even not in use) are consuming SDE connections and ultimately connections are maxed out. I am looking for some recommendations on using 931 SDE with 10 map services.

Thanks
jay

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you described, isn't specific to your configuration of ArcGIS Server 10 and SDE 9.3.1.

This happens irrespective of the version level of SDE and Arcgiserver. You will find that  if you have a large number of instances for your service, that creates an equivalent number of connection. If you have many services, you'll have to increase the max number of connections from 64 to some appropriate value.

Further more, by default the server will maintain an exclusive schema lock on the dataset unless you go and manually edit the cfg file. Querying also has some issues that must be tackled by the SDE administrator.

I am beginning to get convinced that in many cases, especially when data is not updated very often, using File Geodatabases gives better performance than using an SDE geodatabase with arcgis server.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta for the feedback. is this behaviour changed from server 931 to 10. My services are non-pooled with 0-10 for instance range. I think at 931 this setting (0 min instance) didn't consume any connections. Appreciate your feedback. Thanks Jay

Comment: @jay As I mentioned this happens irrespective of your version. If you have your map services set with minimum number of instances=0, then the connection will not be open. But while the services is consumed by a client, an instance is created,  and a connection will be made. This happens in 9.3.1 as well as 10.02